# Python regex swallows one character upon new line substituion

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand what is wrong with my python regex.

**Task:**
I have the following text.

```
This is a red fox\LF
that chases a cat.\LF
\LF
The dog barks.
```

I need to correct the first sentence by joining it and putting on one line:

```
This is a red fox that chases a cat.\LF
The dog barks.
```

**Solution:**
I just came up with plain

```
re.sub(r'(\n)[^\n]', '', text)
```

**Problem:**
However what I get is actually this:

```
This is a red foxhat chases a cat.
he dog barks.
```

I was sure that the substitution should have replaced only the grouped `(\n)`. What is the correct regex for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are consuming the `t` and the `T` because your pattern matches a newline **and** the immeditely following character.

You can use a capture group to remember what the character was, and insert it back into the string.

```
re.sub(r'\n([^\n])', r'\1', text)
```

Or use a lookahead to check the next character but not capture it <sub>(in your particular case, this can be a negative lookahead since you are checking for *no* newline)</sub>:

```
re.sub(r'\n(?!\n)', r'', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\.)\\LF\W+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qR1aK8/1)**

[image]

You also could use:

```
(?<!\.)\\LF$
```

but you would get a different output as you specified.

Comment: this should be less complicated than using "Negative Lookbehind", but thanks.

Comment: @minerals I understand that the syntax can be ugly but if you look at it by parts it means: "Match \LF if it doesn't have a dot before".

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are saying now is to search for any new-line followed by a non new-line character and replace both characters by an empty string.

But if you don't include that second character you match any new-line in your string and that is not what you want.

To be able to have a strict regex but not replace everything you match you have to use capturing groups `(...)` In a regex something between parenthesis is captured and stored.

When you make your substitution you can access those stored groups by using `\index`.
So `\1` for the first captured group `\2` for the second, etc.

For your problem you could use a regex that matches any new-line that is not preceded by a point. `([^\.])\n`. Of course if that preceding character is not a point you want to keep it. So you capture it. And put it back in your substitution like so:

```
re.sub(r'([^\.])\n', '\1 ', text)
```

[Example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vA6dN1/1)