# How to create a regex pattern to pull a character out of a list of variously structured strings?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using regex to pull the letter "u" out of an address string, but only when it is being used as an abbreviation (u, u., U, U., etc). However, the issue I am running is that the list of strings I have are messy and filled with mistakes. I have already attempted to pull what I need out a variety of mistakes I have seen in the data. I know I must be missing something small, but any help is appreciated.

I have tried these regex expressions:

- (\s(u|U)?.?,?.?\s) <- seems a bit funky
- [^\w+][uU]
- [^\w+][uU][^tca]

I also have another idea of getting around this problem which would require pulling apart the addresses (split between street, number, etc), and then fix the street part and glue it back together. I have had some luck actually pulling just the number part out:

- (\d+-\d+|\d+/*\w*|(-))

However, I would like to see where I am messing up in the regex expression that should be selecting the "u." Regex101.com has been my best friend with this, and I would not have made it this far without it.

```py
test_strings = [
    "Holics u 5/a",
    "Holics U 5/a",
    "Holics u5/a",
    "Huolics u 5/a",
    "Holics u. 5/a",
    "Holuics u5",
    "Holics and other stuff u more stuff after 5",
    "Houlics utca 5"
]

# two regex patterns I have considered 

print("First regex pattern ------------------------------------")
pattern = r"[^\w+][uU]"
replacement_text = " utca "

for item in test_strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern,replacement_text,item))

print("\nSecond regex pattern ------------------------------------")
pattern = r"[^\w+][uU][^tca]"
replacement_text = " utca "

for item in test_strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern,replacement_text,item))
```

results from the above code:

First regex pattern:

```py
Holics utca  5/a
Holics utca  5/a
Holics utca 5/a
Huolics utca  5/a
Holics utca . 5/a
Holuics utca 5
Holics and other stuff utca  more stuff after 5
Houlics utca tca 5 # <-------------------------------- issue
```

Second regex pattern:

```py
Holics utca 5/a
Holics utca 5/a
Holics utca /a # <----------------------------------- issue
Huolics utca 5/a
Holics utca  5/a
Holuics utca  <-------------------------------------- issue
Holics and other stuff utca more stuff after 5
Houlics utca 5
```

Everything works except for the last line ("Houlics utca tca 5") in the first regex pattern, and when I try to create an expression to also consider strings that contain "utca," I lose out on the numbers in strings like "Holics u5/a."

For the most part, I expect the outcome to be:

- Holics u. 5/a -----> Holics utca 5/a

As a final note, I have functions that remove periods and white space.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\b[uU](?=\b|\d)\.?\s*', 'utca ', s)`, see https://regex101.com/r/WgFPl5/1

Comment: Voting to close because there are multiple questions here: 1)avoid swallowing the digit 2)conditionally insert a space.

Comment: The 1st is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653891/python-regex-swallows-one-character-upon-new-line-substituion, the 2nd of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391099/python-regex-conditional-in-re-sub-how

Comment: This question is by no means a dupe of any of those questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'\b[uU](?=\b|\d)\.?\s*', 'utca ', s)
```

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[uU]` - `u` or `U`
- `(?=\b|\d)` - there must be a word boundary or a digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Alternatively, you may use

```
re.sub(r'\b[uU](?=\b|(?![^\W\d_]))\.?\s*', 'utca ', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WgFPl5/1) and [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WgFPl5/2).

Here, instead of the digit requirement, the `(?![^\W\d_])` fails if the next char is a letter.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev 1) It does match `u.`, see my *both* demos. Also, `\s*` trims the match on the right, since the space is added in the replacement pattern.

Comment: the q is too broad btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299694/how-to-create-a-regex-pattern-to-pull-a-character-out-a-list-of-variously-struct#comment99212208_56299694

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I do not see what you are driving at. The links do not lead to any solution that can be used here. Please do not post off-topic comments with your opinions. If you think it is a dupe, vote to close the question. Please remove your comments to my answer, they are too chatty as they are not relevent and not true to life.

Comment: SO Q&As aren't supposed to cover every specific situation. In your answer, the `(?=\d)` part is covered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25653966/648265, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52392221/648265 is a cleaner solution than the hack with `\s*`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Can you please prove your point with a code snippet? Why do you suggest using `.*` to match everything instead of trimming trailing whitespace after the `u` word? It will remove everything. Also, it is not evident how `(?=\b|(?![^\W\d_]))` is "covered" with ``r'\n(?!\n)'``. I do not think that any question where a lookahead is necessary in the answer is a dupe of that question, is it?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b[uU]\.?(?=\s|(\d))', lambda m: 'utca'+(' ' if m.group(1) else ''), text)`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev This will work if the point is to match `u` or `U` followed with an optional `.` and then there must be a space or a digit. However, it is much more complex and not any "cleaner" from my first suggestion (note I have two). The lambda expression will make it more resource consuming, so your suggestion is less efficient. BTW, you are free to add it as an answer.

Comment: In Python, cleanness comes before efficiency, especially when giving advice to novices (or at the very least, requires an explanation why you are going for a convoluted solution when a straightforward one exists). I have a hard time understanding what exactly `(?![^\W\d_])` would match, that's 3 levels of negation!

Comment: "match `u` or `U` followed with an optional `.` and then there must be a space or a digit" -- that's exactly what OP's examples have.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Again, that is *your opnion*, it is not at all convoluted: `[^\W\d_]` is a well-known Python regex construct matching any letter. `(?![^\W\d_])` just means "no letter right after". As clean and efficient as could be.